# Do I have to say how I'm ordering my cards after Scrying?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When you Surveil or Scry more than 1 card and announce to your opponent "I leave the 2 on Top (or bottom 2)" do you have to announce the order in which they cards are placed?

"I left both on top - In the same order", 
"I left both on top - but switched the order they'll be drawn", or simply say that you Top both (or bottom both) and no need to announce the order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell them how many cards are placed in which location, but need not reveal whether their order has changed.

> 401.4. If an effect puts two or more cards in a specific position in a library at the same time, the owner of those cards may arrange them in any order. That library's owner doesn't reveal the order in which the cards go into the library.

Comment: I imagine a scry 4 a bit convoluted otherwise "i put the third card first from the bottom, the first one second, then the second one first from the top and the fourth card second from the top" :D